# browserHistory.replace bring me to the path "/"

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I use browserHistory (from react-router) to change url. After a click event I call method that do :

`browserHistory.replace('/newPath')`

but sometimes (not always) this action send me to the "/" of the router.

`

```
    <Router history={browserHistory}>

        <Route
            path="/"
            component={rest => (
                    <AppComponent
                        {...rest}
                        top={<HeaderComponent {...rest} />}
                        left={<DrawerContainer {...rest} />}
                        center={<DashBoard {...rest} />}
                        right={<ContextInfos {...rest} />}
                        bottom={<BottomMenuPrimary {...rest} />}
                    />
            )}
        />

    </Router>

</Provider>
```

`

Someone have and idea ?

Comment: Could you provide the code for your routes?

Comment: I added the routes :)

Comment: Where is /newPath routes defined, also which version of react-router are you using

Comment: `"react-router": "3.0.2",`

this line `browserHistory.replace('/newPath')` is in a children component of 'ContextInfos'